# Can't set picture size when capturing image with AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I have a straightforward implementation of capturing a picture with a preview using AVFoundation: https://gist.github.com/1933313

Everything works perfectly except that my picture resolution is 304x400.

My problems is that as soon as I try to change the default `sessionPreset` (line 16 & 17) to something as small as `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480` it stopes working: it reaches line 60 and the call to `[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection]` will throw the exception

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:] - inactive/invalid connection passed.'
```

because `- (AVCaptureConnection*)getConnection` will return nil (line 61)

Anyone has any idea why this is happening ?

PS: The device on which I test is an iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in their twisted doc :). [Here is the answer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW30): the iPhone 3G does not support 640x480 resolution. Now, why it supports 400x304 & 1600x1200 but no other resolutions in between, it eludes me ...